# using MockBackend to test function that then calls .map

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, angular2-testing

I am trying to write unit tests for my service which makes Http requests.

I have a service that returns a `Http.get()` request followed by a `.map()`. I am having trouble getting my mocked backend to return something that doesn't error on the `.map()`. The error I'm getting is:

```
this._http.get(...).map is not a function
```

I have been using [this article](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-angular-2-http-services-with-jasmine) as my main guide throughout.

If I remove the `.map()` from my service function, I don't get any errors. How can I get my mocked response to have a `.map()` function  that I can call?

**Note: I am currently using RC.4**

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AppSettings } from '../../../settings';
import { Brand } from '../../models/index';

@Injectable()
export class BrandDataService {

  allBrands : Brand[];
  groups : any;
  groupNames : string[];

  constructor (
    private _http : Http
  ) {}

  /**
  * Get all brands
  */
  public getAllBrands () :Observable<any> {

    let url = AppSettings.BRAND_API_URL + 'brands';
    return this._http.get( url )
    .map( this.createAndCacheBrands )
    .catch( (error) => {
      return Observable.throw( error );
    });        
  }

  private createAndCacheBrands (res:Response) {
    ...
  }

}
```

And here is my spec file, which is using `MockBackend` and other associated libraries to mock the backend for these tests:

```
// vendor dependencies
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { addProviders, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

// Service to test
import { BrandDataService } from './brandData.service';


describe( 'Brand data service', () => {

  let service : BrandDataService = null;
  let backend : MockBackend = null;

  // Provide a mock backend implementation
  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      MockBackend,
      BaseRequestOptions,
      {
        provide : Http,
        useFactory : (backendInstance : MockBackend, defaultOptions : BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
        },
        deps : [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      },
      BrandDataService
    ])
  })

  beforeEach (inject([BrandDataService, MockBackend], (_service : BrandDataService, mockBackend : MockBackend) => {
    service = _service;
    backend = mockBackend;
  }));

  it ('should return all brands as an Observable<Response> when asked', (done) => {
    // Set the mock backend to respond with the following options:
backend.connections.subscribe((connection : MockConnection) => {
    // Make some expectations on the request
  expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Get);
    // Decide what to return
    let options = new ResponseOptions({
      body : JSON.stringify({
        success : true
      })
    });
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
  });

  // Run the test.
  service
  .getAllBrands()
  .subscribe(
    (data) =>  {
      expect(data).toBeDefined();
      done();
    }
  )
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `rxjs` so you can use `map`:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Or, you can import only `map` operator so your app doesn't load files you won't use:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: Oh I'm so annoyed - I had this issue earlier today elsewhere and fixed it. I don't know why it didn't occur to me here. Thank you for pointing out the obvious!

Comment: @dafyddPrys Don't worry, it happens to everyone. I made this exact mistake two or three times, that's how I remembered it. :-)

Comment: Do you know what I need to import to get `.map().catch()` to work? - EDIT: turns out it's 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'.